# how to change size of height OutlineInputBorder?

Tags: flutter

i having issue for error border, how to change size of height for error outlineinputborder? following is the image and code  thank you . [image]

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60,
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            obscureText: obscure,

            // keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: kErrorColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: kErrorColor),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                prefixIcon: icon,
                hintText: hintText,
                hintStyle: kHintTextStyle),
            validator: validatior,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code, You can increase width.

```
 decoration: new InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 5.0),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5.0),
        ),
        hintText: 'Mobile Number',
    ),
```

Comment: Im trying to change height of red line its too small

Comment: I think you are trying to increase the width of the border line right? You can do this by increasing the width.

Comment: im trying to increase height of red outline its does not match size with container

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you wrapped your Textfield with taller Container(height: 60).
And you think that taller Container is your Textfield but it's not.
To make your Textfield taller use contentPadding in InputDecoration

```
// you can change those numbers as you like
decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 0.0),
    ),
```

Comment: only text height is changed the size of red outline not changing